# Multiple input (fmt.Scanln)

Tags: go

Why does this doesn't work, or how to get multiple input with `fmt.Scanln`?

**EDIT:** If I insert more then one word then I get the Error "Scan: expected newline", anything I can do about this?

```
    var username string
    print("Username: ")
    _, err := fmt.Scanln(&username)
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
    }

    var password string
    print("Password: ")
    _, err := fmt.Scanln(&password)
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
    }

    var status string
    print("Status: ")
    _, err := fmt.Scanln(&status)
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(username, password, status)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are re-declaring the err variable multiple times in the same scope.
The compiler error should have made that clear. The following will work:

```
var err error
var username string

print("Username: ")
_, err = fmt.Scanln(&username)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
}

var password string
print("Password: ")
_, err = fmt.Scanln(&password)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
}

var status string
print("Status: ")
_, err = fmt.Scanln(&status)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
}

fmt.Println(username, password, status)
return
```

Comment: Thx, but I get the following error: "main.go:1: undefined: error"

Comment: Use `var err os.Error` and import the package `"os"` instead. The `os.Error` interface was just recently renamed to `error` in the latest weekly.